# What is the correct Xaml syntax (and underlying vb code) to have a event raised by a custom Control handled in a host application view model

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, mvvm, event-handling

I have a wpf Custom Control which is now raising custom events.  In a test project that I have created to test the ongoing development of the control I have placed a copy of my new custom control on the main window.

In the properties dialog for said control I can see my new event and I can type in the name for a handler for it in the code behind the main window and it's not only created for me but when I place a break point on it I see both the sender and my own event args raised in the control.

What I would now like to know Is what is the correct way to alert a viewmodel about that event respecting the principles of MVVM.

Below is the xaml markup for my custom control in the mainwindow of the test application

```
 <WpfControls:VtlDataNavigator  Name="vtlDn"
                                   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Orders}"
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   AddButtonVisibility="True"
                                   CancelNewRecordButtonVisibility="True"
                                   SaveButtonVisibility="True" />
```

The event I want to catch is called 'RecordControlButtonClicked'  and this is the event automatically created in the mainwindow code behind

```
  Private Sub MyCustomHandlerForControlEvent(sender As Object, e As ViewToLearn.WpfControls.VtlDataNavigatorEventArgs) Handles vtlDn.RecordControlButtonClicked

End Sub
```

So now what I'm after is the correct syntax in both the xaml and my new MainWindowViewModel to have this event transferred across to the viewmodel for handling (or suggestions as to the most efficient way to do this idf there is no direct route.
FYI I already have a relay command set up in the test application but the way that I've used it to bind commands in the past doesn't appear to be working with events.

**Edit**

One approach I've tried which appears to work is to add the following in the code behind of the main window's loaded event.

```
    Class MainWindow
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent
        DataContext = New MainWindowViewModel
    End Sub

    Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        Dim mvm As MainWindowViewModel = DirectCast(DataContext, MainWindowViewModel)
        mvm.vtldn = vtlDn
    End Sub
End Class
```

and then add the following in the viewmodel;

```
  Private _vtldn As ViewToLearn.WpfControls.VtlDataNavigator
Public Property vtldn As ViewToLearn.WpfControls.VtlDataNavigator
    Get
        Return _vtldn
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As ViewToLearn.WpfControls.VtlDataNavigator)
        If (_vtldn Is Value) Then Return
        If Not IsNothing(vtldn) Then
            RemoveHandler vtldn.RecordControlButtonClicked, AddressOf MyCustomHandler
        End If
        _vtldn = Value
        If Not IsNothing(vtldn) Then
            AddHandler vtldn.RecordControlButtonClicked, AddressOf MyCustomHandler
        End If
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(NameOf(vtldn)))
    End Set
End Property
Private Sub MyCustomHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As VtlDataNavigatorEventArgs)
    'this does get called when buttons in the custom control are clicked
End Sub
```

However I'm acutely aware that this is not really 'pure' mvvm so if there are better ways to do this I'm open to suggestions.